# Find preceding element using PHP Simple HTML Parser

Tags: php

I have some HTML that is setup like the following (this can be different though!):

```
<table></table>
<h4>Content</h4>
<table></table>
```

I'm using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to loop over a section of code setup like this:

[image]

How can I say something like - "Find the table and the preceding h4, grab the text from the h4 if it exists, if it doesn't then leave blank".

If I just use `$html->find('div[class=product-table] h4');` then it ignores the fact there was no title for the first table.

This is my full code for context:

```
$table_rows = $html->find('div[class=product-table] table');
$tablecounter = 1;
foreach ($table_rows as $table){
  $tablevalue[] =
    array(
        "field_5b3f40cae191b"   => "Table",
    );
}
update_field( $field_key, $tablevalue, $post_id );
```

---

Update:

I've found in the documentation that you can use `prev_sibling()` so I've tried `$table_title = $html->find('div[class=product-table] table')->prev_sibling('h4');` but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: maybe you can search for "</table><h4>" might be easier if your code is uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the example to hopefully show the situation your after, it does assume that the `<h4>` tag is immediately prior to the `<table>` tag.  But it uses the `prev_sibling()` of the table tag you find.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$source = "<html>
<body>
    <div class='product-table'>
        <table>t1</table>
        <h4>Content</h4>
        <table>t2</table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>";

$html = str_get_html($source);
$table_rows = $html->find('div[class=product-table] table');
foreach ($table_rows as $table){
    $prev = $table->prev_sibling();
    if ( !empty($prev) && $prev->tag == "h4")   {
        echo "h4=".(string)$prev->innertext().PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "content=".(string)$table.PHP_EOL;
}
```

echos..

```
content=<table>t1</table>
h4=Content
content=<table>t2</table>
```